# Regex separator for splitting a CSV with double brackets / nd lists

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a .csv following this logic

```
name, number, 2dlist, bool
"entry1", 1, [[0,1],[2,3]], true
"entry2", 2, [[4,5],[6,7]], true
```

What kind of regex do I need to separate the rows to four columns so that everything inside the double square brackets get noted as one column, i.e. [[ ... ]].

I'm new to regex but managed to edit the following code sample

```
df = pd.read_csv("../file.csv", sep=r",(?![^\[]*[\]])",header=0, engine="python")
```

which does work with single brackets but not with double. As in, the comma between the lists `1],[2` gets still recognized as a separator even though it shouldn't.

This is a part of a hobby project and I might change the initial approach for better. However, at this point I'm only curious about the regex that would work in this specific case.

Comment: Ideally your bracketed terms should be doubly quoted i.e. `"[[0,1],[2,3]]"` ... you should fix your source data

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to also show your expected output

Answer (score 1):

With your sample, you can probably split your dataframe with `,`  but maybe it's not so simple:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=', ', engine='python')
print(df)

# Output
       name  number         2dlist  bool
0  "entry1"       1  [[0,1],[2,3]]  True
1  "entry2"       2  [[4,5],[6,7]]  True
```

Comment: list is not in apostrophes so it wont work the comma in between gets parsed as another separator.

Answer (score 0):

if your csv looks like this

```
      name,number,2dlist,bool
0,"entry1",1,"[[0,1],[2,3]]",True
1,"entry2",2,"[[4,5],[6,7]]",True
```

this would work fine:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',')
```

cause now list is stored in between apostrophes, the spaces and comma's in between get ignored. If data is not stored that way good regex codes are required to separate in a generic way. Try adding regex tag to question u might better solutions then.